# Overriding superclass constructor

Tags: java

I have two classes : **Year**  and **LeapYear** setting the days of the year to 365 and 366 respectively within their constructors. I want to achieve something specific here.i want to override the Year's constructor in the LeapYear's constructor to set the number of days to 366? Alternatively i have done the following.

```
public class Year {

private int days;

public Year() {
    this.days = 365;
}
public void setDays(int days) {
    this.days = days;
}

public int getDays() {
    return this.days;
}
```

}

```
public class LeapYear extends Year {

public LeapYear() {
    setDays(366);
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model is wrong and that's why you have trouble with the constructors: it's simply not true that a 366-days-leap-year **is-a** 365-days-year. But that's what you model tries to tell us.

You better model it like that:

```
public abstract class PeriodOfDays {
   int days;
   public PeriodOfDays(int days) { this.days = days; }
}

public class StandardYear extends PeriodOfDays {
   public StandardYear() { super(365); }
}

public class LeapYear extends PeriodOfDays {
   public LeapYear() { super(366); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add a protected constructor that takes it in?

```
public class Year {

private int days;

protected Year(int days) {
   this.days = days;
}

public Year() {
    this(365);
}

public int getDays() {
    return this.days;
}
}

public class LeapYear extends Year {

public LeapYear()  {
  super(366);
}
```

Comment: ``super(arg)`` overrides the constructor parameter ``arg`` from base class, here: ``Year``.

Answer (score 0):

Possible improvement over Daniel's suggestion, since `year.setDays()` just feels very "wrong".  Make the public constructor with a `final` field days.  e.g.

```
public class Year {

private final int days;

protected Year(int days) {
   this.days = days;
}

public Year() {
   this(365);
}


public class LeapYear extends Year {

public LeapYear()  {
  super(366);
}

}
```

NOTE: I agree with @Andreas_D that this whole approach is dubious...